# django-image-cropping how to via view serve cropped image

Tags: django, image, django-models

I am using `django-image-cropping` in my project.

[doc](https://media.readthedocs.org/pdf/django-image-cropping/latest/django-image-cropping.pdf) says:

> The original images are kept intact and only get cropped when they are displayed. Large images are presented in a
>   small format, so even very big images can easily be cropped.

In my model i have fields:

```
logo = ImageCropField(upload_to=get_image_path, null=True, blank=True)
cropping_logo = ImageRatioField('logo', '186x186', size_warning=True)
```

User can adjust cropping of the photo in admin panel. Like in picture below. 
[image]

Changes are kept ONLY in `cropping_logo` field as numeric values indicating the cropping vertices, e.g: `91,0,239,148`

I would like to serve via some url dynamically cropped image based on cropping vertices, but don't know how.

---

UPDATE: Basing on hint of ubadub to use PIL I figured out following solution using such view.

```
def thumbnail(request, image_file):
    image_file = '/'.join(('img', image_file))
    f = MyModel.objects.get(logo=image_file)
    img = Image.open(''.join((os.getcwd(), f.logo.url)))
    box = tuple([int(i) for i in f.cropping_logo.split(',')])
    img = img.crop(box)
    response = HttpResponse(mimetype="image/png")
    img.save(response, "jpeg")
    return response
```

needed imports are:

```
import os
from PIL import Image
from django.http import HttpResponse
```

your url pattern may look as follows:

```
url(r'^thumbnail/(?P<image_file>.+)$', 'yourapp.views.thumbnail'),
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, one option is to serve some view at some url that returns the image cropped with css:

Example css:

```
img 
{
position:absolute;
clip:rect(0px,60px,200px,0px);
}
```

where the clip:rect has the dimensions defined in your model.

The css could be inline (bad practice, but whatever) or in a dynamically served css file (also probably not the best idea to serve a css file dynamically, but necessary in this case).

However this would still serve a html page. So another option if you want to serve a page of mime-type image, then do this, but you'll need PIL (Python Image Library):

```
response = HttpResponse(mimetype="image/png")
img.save(response, "PNG")
return response
```

where `img` is the original image cropped to the specified dimensions.

And of course replace png with whatever file format your image is in.